# I can't connect to my Parse Dashboard from my Android Studio app

Tags: parse-platform

I've been trying to solve this issue of the I/o failure with my app. I put the android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" but even though it stills failing and I don't know what should I do now. This is my AndroidManifest.xml file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.parseserver01">



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ParseServer01">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the App.java file.

```css
package com.example.parseserver01;
import com.parse.Parse;
import android.app.Application;

public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
                .applicationId("HSBN")
                // if defined
                .clientKey(null)
                .server("http://localhost:1337/parse/")
                .build()
        );
    }
}
```

And the MainActivity.java file of my android app.

```css
package com.example.parseserver01;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject("TodoList");
        parseObject.put("todo", "todo");
        parseObject.saveInBackground();

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("TodoList");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    System.out.println("-------------------------IT WORKS!!!!-------------------");
                    String dato = parseObject.getString("todo");
                    System.out.println(dato);
                    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("-------------------------FAILURE-----------------------------");
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    System.out.println(e.getCode());
                    System.out.println(e.getCause());
                    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And finally, this is the configuration of my Parse server (I'm using the parse-server-example because I'm just testing).

```js
const config = {
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb+srv://hsbn:123@cluster0.omrau.mongodb.net/ParseData',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'HSBN',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'kqsPdEFbul', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse', // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ['Posts', 'Comments'], // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  },
};
// Client-keys like the javascript key or the .NET key are not necessary with parse-server
// If you wish you require them, you can set them as options in the initialization above:
// javascriptKey, restAPIKey, dotNetKey, clientKey

var ParseDashboard = require('parse-dashboard');

var dashboard = new ParseDashboard({
  "apps": [
    {
      "serverURL": "http://localhost:1337/parse",
      "appId": "HSBN",
      "masterKey": "kqsPdEFbul",
      "appName": "Android Test"
    }
  ]
});
```

I've also tried the /test of parse server and it completes all the 3 tests. Also I'm running the android app in my cellphone. Please help me.

Comment: You said that you are running Parse Server on your local machine and the app in your cellphone. So that's probably the problem. When you set `http://localhost:1337/parse` in your app sdk, the app will try to connect to the localhost, which will be the cellphone itself, and not your machine. You'd need to change the initialization to point out to your machine ip (and make sure your machine has open 1337 port).

Comment: mmm so i have to put my machine IP? the one that appears with ipconfig command?

Comment: Yes. But you have to make sure you have open ports for that.

Comment: OMG it actually works!! Thank you so much Davi

Comment: Cool. I'm glad it worked!